# OR function for character values in R

Tags: r

I want to check whether a variable of a data frame contains at least one of the values in the least. I want the R equivalent of the OR function, look something like this (the OR function here is clearly wrong)

```
lost$League =ifelse(grepl(OR("Academy","H.S.") , lost$Drafted.From), "Highschool","Not highschool")
```

`lost$League` will have value "Highschool" if `lost$Drafted.From` contains either "Academy" or "H.S.", and have value "No highschool" otherwise.

I am new to R and english is not my first language so I am sorry if my question is not really clear.

Comment: in `grep*` you use the vertical pipe `|` for OR - `grepl("Acadamny|H.S.", x)` (where x is the data you're searching)

Comment: You don't need to make grepl call as I have shown.

Comment: @khrm yes, you need `grep`/`grepl` because `lost$Drafted.From` can **contain** the words *"Academy"* or *"H.S."*

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus It's quite simple query. No need for grep. My query is giving me correct answer. You can use grep also. But I generally use it when I am using regex.

Comment: @khrm It depends on the interpretation of the word *"contains"*. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the interpretation of the word *"contains"*. If the `Drafted.From` column only contains single words or complete (exact) matches, then the vertical pipe `|` or the `%in%` operator will be sufficient. Else you will need `grepl`.

Some example data:

```
lost <- data.frame(drafted.from.1 = c('Academy','College','H.S.'),
                   drafted.from.2 = c('He studied at the Academy','She went to College','He attended Dartmore H.S.'))
```

For the `drafted.from.1` column, you can use `%in%` as follows:

```
ifelse(lost$drafted.from.1 %in% c("Academy","H.S."), "Highschool", "Not highschool")
```

which gives the correct result:

```
[1] "Highschool"     "Not highschool" "Highschool"
```

But also `grepl` works in this case:

```
> ifelse(grepl("Academy|H.S.", lost$drafted.from.1), "Highschool", "Not highschool")
[1] "Highschool"     "Not highschool" "Highschool"
```

For the `drafted.from.2` column, you need `grepl` to assign the `Highschool` and `Not highschool` values:

```
ifelse(grepl("Academy|H.S.", lost$drafted.from.2), "Highschool", "Not highschool")
```

which gives the correct result:

```
[1] "Highschool"     "Not highschool" "Highschool"
```

With regard to the `drafted.from.2` column, the `%in%` (or the use of the `|` OR operator) will not give the correct result:

```
> ifelse(lost$drafted.from.2 %in% c("Academy","H.S."), "Highschool", "Not highschool")
[1] "Not highschool" "Not highschool" "Not highschool"
```

Let's now apply this knowledge to the dataframe:

```
lost$League.1 <- ifelse(lost$drafted.from.1 %in% c("Academy","H.S."), "Highschool", "Not highschool")
lost$League.2 <- ifelse(grepl("Academy|H.S.", lost$drafted.from.2), "Highschool", "Not highschool")
```

The result:

```
> lost
  drafted.from.1            drafted.from.2       League.1       League.2
1        Academy He studied at the Academy     Highschool     Highschool
2        College       She went to College Not highschool Not highschool
3           H.S.      He finished his H.S.     Highschool     Highschool
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `|` (or) operator like this:

```
mydf$lost <- ifelse(lost$Drafted.From == "Academy" | lost$Drafted.From == "H.S.", "Highschool", "Not highschool")
```